# How to prevent/restrict blank values from being added to a mysql database in java?

Tags: java, mysql

I wanted to prevent my java program from accepting/inserting blank or "" value in the database. I already set columns username and password as not null though but it keeps on accepting blank or "" values.

heres a part my code for adding values into the DB:

```
    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

        try{
          theQuery("insert into accounts (username,password) values ('"+user1.getText()+"', '"+pass1.getText()+"')");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to add record to the database");
        }

}
```

P.S. password is not hashed since this is for activity only.

Comment: you need to check for blank values before adding it in query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
String str=user1.getText();

       if ("".equals(str)){  //User have not entered anything. 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter your name.");
        nameField.requestFocusInWindow();
        //Do NOT loop here.
    }
    else { 
        //Do everything you need to do when the user have entered something
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I have this idea a while ago and tried to construct it but you made it much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

FYI You might also want to look at Apache Commons StringUtils for testing of null, empty, blank strings:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

It has lots of handy (nullsafe) methods like "isBlank", "isEmpty" etc

Replacing idioms like:

```
if (myString != null && myString != "")
```

With:

```
if (!StringUtils.isBlank(myString))
```